# Is there a way to add providers to an auth existing user? - Supabase - Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, oauth, supabase

With Firebase, I was able to do the following:

```
final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(idToken: idToken);
//OR OTHER PROVIDERS
final credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(email: emailAddress, password: password);
//ADD PROVIDER TO CURRENT USER
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential);
```

With Supabase I know these two things; users can be created with OAuth providers and, if the email of that provider user matches an existing user email, the provider is automatically added to that existing user. What I don't know is how to add providers to a user manually.

Example 1:

1. App requires every user to have an Email & Password
2. User signs up with phone auth or OAth
3. User needs to add Email & Password provider to their profile

Example 2:

1. User signs up with an Email & Password provider
2. User wants to be able to sign in with OAuth or phone auth
3. User needs to sign in to OAuth then that provider should be added to the existing Email & Password account

Answer (score 0):

Currently in Supabase email address is the unique identifier of users. If a user that has signed up with email and password also signs up with their Google account using OAuth with the same email address, those two accounts will automatically be merged.

Comment: I saw a similar answer on a different post, so as I said, I know that accounts with the same email will automatically be merged. Are you sure the email is used as a user's unique identifier? That would be strange, considering each user has a UUID, which is what would usually be used. Also, what would the unique identifier be if a user signed up with their phone number and no email?

Comment: @Globe Okay, maybe `unique identifier` was a confusing term to use here. All I meant was that if a user tries to create a new account with the same email address, they will be merged to the existing account. Not sure about phone numbers, but might be fun to try out!